# Haxe uncaught global exception handler

Tags: exception, error-handling, haxe, hxcpp

I am writing UI of an application using Haxe for CPP targets. I need to intercept haxe error/exceptions before it crashes the App.
Below is an example of code which crashes the application:

```
@:final private function callFoo(classA : IInterface) : Void
{
    if ((mClassLevelVariable != null) && (classA != mClassLevelVariable))
    {
        throw new Error("Can not work with " + Type.getClassName(Type.getClass((classA))));
    }
}
```

I need to intercept the crash before error like given above crashes the application. Do we have any support in Haxe like Java provides `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply wrap your `main()` in a try-catch:

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        try {
            entryPoint();
        } catch (e:Any) {
            // do something with e
        }
    }
}
```

That's pretty much [how for instance OpenFL implements Flash's uncaught error event](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/blob/0c5f33a1f9abeb99ea9303bff1f2b806516ba07d/assets/templates/haxe/ApplicationMain.hx#L145-L160) as well.

Note that not all exceptions can be caught this way in hxcpp. Null pointer exceptions for instance can only be caught if `HXCPP_CHECK_POINTER` is defined.

Comment: exactly the kind of answer i was looking for. Suppose i want to crash the app after i've intercepted the error and done everything i needed, then how can we accomplish that?

For example, i intercepted the exception/error then i logged something in server and then i want to crash the application. then how can we do that if we have this kind of try/catch block on the entryPoint?

Comment: Just re-throw the error with `throw e;` - not sure if hxcpp allows preserving the callstack, but some platforms do: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4159.